# J K Flip Flop and Boolean Algebra

Tags: flipflop, boolean-algebra

> Y=K'J'Q+K'J+KJQ'
>
> The output Y should be that of a JK flip-flop. That is:   Y=JQ'+K'Q

I tried to solve the following way:

**1.** Y=K'J'Q+K'J+KJQ'

**2.** =K'(J'Q+J)+KJQ'

**3.** =JK'+K'Q+JKQ'

**4.** =J(K'+KQ')+K'Q

**5.** =J(K'+Q')+K'Q

**6.** =JK'+JQ'+K'Q

It appears as if the term JK' is 0. Please help.

Comment: Explain the last step, please?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Done

Comment: Try writing down the truth tables of the original function and the target one. If these are different, then you have missed something (or the question author did)

Comment: Also draw out the waveforms, with arrows to show what signals (some are anded) affect the outputs, at what times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the original equation:

Y = K'J'Q + K'J + KJQ'

The trick is to create two terms that are equivalent to the middle term, using the fact that X + X' = 1:

Y = J'K'Q + JK'(Q + Q') + JKQ'

Y = J'K'Q + JK'Q + JK'Q' + JKQ'

Now factor the pairs of terms:

Y = K'Q(J + J') + JQ'(K + K')

Simplify, again using the fact that X + X' = 1:

Y = K'Q + JQ'

This is really obvious if you draw the Karnaugh map for the function. The JK' term is redundant, given the other two terms.

Comment: Sir can you please answer this question : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/404330/115973