# How do we decide which circuit is a latch?

Tags: logic-gates, latch

1. Will A and B always be the complement of one another regardless of
   what logic gates we use in the latch-like circuit? For instance (the
   two circuits shown as examples):
2. How do we decide whether A and B will be the complement of one
   another or not?
3. How to find the invalid states?
4. Are these two latches?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNf8Rw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**OR**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftsEx1.png)</sup>

I have tried following a few videos for instance [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rIXiDhFiqT4). But the presenter says that a certain state is invalid because Q and Q' should be the complement of each other. But how do we decide/prove that Q and Q' are the complement of one another?

UPDATE:

Truth Table of First Circuit:

[image]

How do I derive answers to the above questions from here.

Comment: the video that you linked show you exactly how to prove which state is invalid in the first 5 minutes of the video ..... which part of the video was unclear to you?

Comment: @jsotola He says (1,1) state is invalid because in that case both Q=0 and Q'=0. He did not mention why Q and Q' should be the complement of one another.

Comment: no! not what he says! ..... what he does. ... do the same, draw a logic diagram for each of your circuits.   .... please add the logic diagrams that you have produced to your question

Comment: @Soumee, i just noticed that you are not the OP.    ..... `Q'` means `not Q`, which is a complement of `Q` ...... you do not need to have a `Q'` as an output, but you will most likely need it internally

Comment: @jsotola I have added the truth table.....Can you help me answer the above questions....

Answer (score 2):

To have a valid latch there must be three distinct values of the inputs:

1. One set of input values that forces the latch to a logic 1 state
2. One set of input values that forces the latch to a logic 0 state
3. One set of input values that holds the current state, whether it is 0 or 1

A valid latch circuit must also have an output signal, typically called `Q`, that reflects the stored state of the latch.

Set up the truth tables for each circuit and see if you can find the necessary input conditions for the circuit to be a latch.

Comment: If I draw the truth table, how will I watch out for the invalid states?

Comment: How would I know which state is invalid?

Comment: @Soumee, do not ask those questions until after you draw the truth table

Comment: @jsotola Added....Please Check

Comment: You added a truth table. Can you recognise a set of input values that statisfies Elliot's condition 3?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen R=0 , H=1 holds the current state. Is the truth table correct  for both A(n+1) and B(n+1)?